# How to select subfolder using File component of Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have Camel application based on Spring Boot, there is a defined route that should poll specific folder (e.g. `C:/test`). In this folder there are sub-folders named by ordinal date of the day: 196, 197, 198 etc. I need to filter these subfolders and pick up the folder with max value in its name. In other words I need dynamically choose the folder for File component, e.g. `C:/test/197`.

I tried to use parameter `filterDirectory`, e.g by setting it to `"${date:now:yyyy}"`. I tried other configurations of folder structure and it seems to me that this parameter doesn't work.

Can such selection of sub-folders be implemented using Camel?

**Update**:
Currently there is no an opportunity to scan the root folder for sub-folders from code, so solution should rely only on Camel framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the configurable options to filter files or folders do not work for your case, you can implement a `GenericFileFilter` class and configure it as `filter` option.

The `GenericFileFilter` class contains just an `accept` method that returns `true` (file is imported) or `false` (file is ignored).

Notice that you need to configure `recursive=true` if you want to **process subdirectories and their files**. Without the recursive option, Camel ignores all subdirectories by default.

If you activate the `recursive` option, the `accept` method of `GenericFileFilter` is called for files and folders. Don't forget to handle the folders. If you return `false` for a directory all files in it are ignored.

So for your case (import all files from a certain subfolder) I see something like this

```
@Override
public boolean accept(GenericFile file) {
    correctSubfolder = ... calculate name

    if (file.isDirectory() && file.getFileName().equals(correctSubfolder)) {
        // walk into the correct subdirectory
        return true;
    }

    if (!file.isDirectory() && file.getParent().equals(correctSubfolder)) {
        // only process files of the correct subdirectory
        return true;
    }

    // ignore everything else
    return false;
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this feature, but this only works for files in selected parent directory. If I define `GenericFileFilter` it will poll only files in parent directory disregarding subfolders. The question is how to dynamically select subfolder using File component.

Comment: I just extended my answer. The FileFilter processes files and folders. But if you return false for a folder, it does not "reach" the files in it.

Comment: I rechecked this with next configuration: I have the folder `C:/test/2021` only with 3 subfolders (contains some files) and no files in it. The route has next endpoint: `file:C:/test/2021?noop=true&filter=#fileFilter`, `FileFilter` registered as `@Component` and is initiated while app start. I put some breakpoints in `FileFilter` and the app doesn't reach them. If I put file in root directory  the app start polls this file. So I can say that bean of `GenericFileFilter` doesn't see directories in my case.

Comment: Is it possible that subdirectories only reach the FileFilter when you also configure `recursive=true`? I can't remember if the `recursive` option is sort of a "master switch" for subdirectories or if the FileFilter is individual from other options

Comment: I just checked and verified this. You have to activate `recursive=true` to get subfolders and their files in the FileFilter.

Comment: yes, I've checked it too. But if I filter files and accept only sub-folders how can I select and proceed the desired sub-folder in one poll?

Comment: You have to implement the accept method so that it returns true for the correct subfolder and false for all other subfolders. Like this the method only gets the files in the root directory (always) as well as those in the correct subfolder (because you returned true).

Comment: I extended my answer specific to your case

Comment: Thanks, but as I pointed earlier the whole problem is to find this `correctSubfolder` using Camel. I'm going to run app from Linux-server and shared folder will be on Windows machine, so it not so easy to make a call to the root directory and find all sub-folders - I need to find and test some Samba client. That's why I want to solve it using Camel.

Comment: Oh, since you can access the files with Camels File component I expected that you can also access the files and subfolders with Java to determine the correct subfolder.